# Error SMTP can't send an email from gmail

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am currently trying to use `smtp` to send an email from my gmail to another yahoo email address. I've enabled less secure apps from my Gmail account. I've also went through Gmail Captcha. I also tried to add a port number (587, 2525), but it didn't work. I can't get the code to work. I posted my code here, and after it the error message.

The weird thing is that, this used to work for me few months ago!!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import lxml
import smtplib

my_email = "MY_EMAIL@gmail.com"
password = "MY_PASSWORD"

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Plus-60-Programmable/dp/B01NBKTPTS/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=34PO9PKK0CUSX" \
      "&keywords=instant%2Bpot&qid=1639842722&sprefix=instant%2Caps%2C76&sr=8-1-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWV" \
      "yPUEyUlM1TDQ5N0RQS1VXJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzc4NTk5M0c2VVhTVlE1Q1lBTyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMjE0NzMyNUlTVUg0V1" \
      "BYQTZWJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ&th=1 "

TARGET_PRICE = 200

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
website_html = response.text

print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, "lxml")

price = float(soup.find(id="attach-base-product-price").attrs["value"])
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()


# sending a notification email
if price <= TARGET_PRICE:
    message = f"{title} is now {price}"

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        result = connection.login(my_email, password)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=my_email,
            to_addrs="SOME_EMAIL@yahoo.com",
            msg=f"Subject:Amazon Price Alert!\n\n{message}\n{URL}"
        )

print("done")
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Charaf/PycharmProjects/Intermediate+/AmazonPriceTracker/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with a Google App Password (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)? I just tested it with my amazon price checker which is pretty similar and it works on mine, with a google app password.

This is what I normally use to send a mail though-

```
    def Send_Mail(email,password,remail): #Function for sending a mail to the user 
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    
    server.login(email,password)
    
    body = f"Price Fell Down\n\nCheck -{url}"
    
    server.sendmail(email,remail,body)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error with this method!

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses an IMPLICIT TLS connection (SSL) by default.

This means you don't upgrade a Gmail connection with `starttls()`. Instead you connect to a different port; the ssl port `465`.

Remove:

```
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
```

..and keep only one `server.ehlo()` while of course connecting on port `465`.

In the list below, your code should work as is for any service other than Gmail & Rackspace.

- GMAIL.COM - IMPLICIT TLS connection (SSL)
- RACKSPACE.COM - IMPLICIT TLS connection (SSL)
- MAILTRAP.COM - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- iCLOUD.COM - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- OUTLOOK - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- OUTLOOK.COM - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- YAHOO.COM - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- MAIL.COM - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- AOL.COM - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)
- COMCAST.NET - EXPLICIT TLS connection (STARTTLS)